# WireGuard VPN не работает

Tags: vpn, wireguard, gpt

установил wireguard сервер на vps. Всякие facebook и инстаграммы работают. А вот сервис openai работает только с айфона, на ноуте говорит что не работает в России. В какой то момент попробовал прокинуть ssh тунель до vps, и гпт стал доступен с ноутбука тоже. Потом пришлось формтануть систему и после этого не помогает ни тунель, ни wireguard. Пробовал поднять wireguard на другом хочтинге результат точно такой же - телефон конектится к гпт, нойт нет. Запустить гпт очень надо иммено на ноуте, ос ubuntu, мб есть какие то другие способы получить доступ к гпт...

Answer (score 2):

VPN подключения на зарубежные серверы по протоколам OpenVPN и Wireguard блокируются российскими провайдерами с 15 января 2024 года. Пока неизвестно заблокированы ли они перманентно или это учение перед выборами.

Как альтернативу VPN можно использовать shadowsocks proxy, или, если не требуется шифрование трафика, любое другое proxy решение.